# Pot selection for fudge

Tags: equipment, candy

Is there a particular kind/size of pot recommended for making fudge?

Comment: Very fluffy indica.

Comment: Any kind of shake should do.  1/4 to 1/2 oz

Answer (score 2):

You should use a large, heavy pan with a thick metal base, definitely not non-stick.

Comment: Why not non-stick?

Comment: @basilard99: Because at the temperature you need for fudge, the non-stick coating tends to break down, in my experience.